# Edge version 112 latest update broke my webview2 devtool automation

Tags: automation, devtools, webview2

Edge version 112 latest update(4/7/2023) broke my webview2 devtools automation, it is able to get the remote session(webview2 app) of the browser but could not run JS on it.

with latest Edge updates i should be able to run JS on the webview2 browser session, which is not working currently.

Comment: Please file a bug https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues and say what CoreWebView2 APIs you are using and if you are using CallDevToolsMethod say what CDP methods and events you are using and what is going wrong with them. Please also include the version you are using of the WebView2 Runtime/Edge, and the version of the WebView2 SDK/WinApp SDK you are using. Thx.